# .NET 6 Report Designer System.Runtime.Serialization.Primivites Version 6.0.0.0 Error

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, devexpress, report-designer

The backend of our project was .Net standard, the frontend was .Net Framework 4.7.2, we migrated our C# project to **.Net 6**.

We used the DevExpress toolkit on UI components. After the migration, while the WinForm designers are working fine, I am getting an error in the **report designer**.

The error says **System.Runtime.Serialization.Primitives Version 6.0.0.0** not found.
When I looked at the nuget packages, I saw that it existed until version 4.3.0. Shouldn't the SDK provide this package? I'm so confused.

[image]

**Stack Info:**

```
1.   Hide Call Stack 
 
at System.ModuleHandle.ResolveType(RuntimeModule module, Int32 typeToken, IntPtr* typeInstArgs, Int32 typeInstCount, IntPtr* methodInstArgs, Int32 methodInstCount, ObjectHandleOnStack type)
at System.ModuleHandle.ResolveTypeHandleInternal(RuntimeModule module, Int32 typeToken, RuntimeTypeHandle[] typeInstantiationContext, RuntimeTypeHandle[] methodInstantiationContext)
at System.Reflection.RuntimeModule.ResolveType(Int32 metadataToken, Type[] genericTypeArguments, Type[] genericMethodArguments)
at System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.FilterCustomAttributeRecord(CustomAttributeRecord caRecord, MetadataImport scope, Assembly& lastAptcaOkAssembly, RuntimeModule decoratedModule, MetadataToken decoratedToken, RuntimeType attributeFilterType, Boolean mustBeInheritable, Object[] attributes, IList derivedAttributes, RuntimeType& attributeType, IRuntimeMethodInfo& ctor, Boolean& ctorHasParameters, Boolean& isVarArg)
at System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.GetCustomAttributes(RuntimeModule decoratedModule, Int32 decoratedMetadataToken, Int32 pcaCount, RuntimeType attributeFilterType, Boolean mustBeInheritable, IList derivedAttributes, Boolean isDecoratedTargetSecurityTransparent)
at System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.GetCustomAttributes(RuntimeType type, RuntimeType caType, Boolean inherit)
at System.ComponentModel.TypeDescriptor.CheckDefaultProvider(Type type)
at System.ComponentModel.TypeDescriptor.NodeFor(Type type, Boolean createDelegator)
at System.ComponentModel.TypeDescriptor.GetDescriptor(Type type, String typeName)
at System.ComponentModel.TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(Type componentType, Attribute[] attributes)
at DevExpress.Data.Browsing.DataBrowserHelperBase.GetListItemPropertiesByType(Type type, PropertyDescriptor[] listAccessors, Int32 startIndex)
at DevExpress.Data.Browsing.DataBrowserHelperBase.GetListItemProperties(Object list, PropertyDescriptor[] listAccessors)
at DevExpress.Data.Browsing.DataBrowserHelper.GetListItemProperties(Object list, PropertyDescriptor[] listAccessors)
at DevExpress.XtraReports.Native.Data.CustomRelatedListBrowser.GetItemProperties()
at DevExpress.Data.Browsing.Design.PropertiesProvider.ToFakedProperties(Object dataSource, String dataMember, PropertyDescriptor[] properties)
at DevExpress.Data.Browsing.Design.PropertiesProvider.ProcessProperties(PropertyDescriptorCollection properties, Object dataSource, String dataMember)
at DevExpress.Data.Browsing.Design.PropertiesProvider.GetItemProperties(Object dataSource, String dataMember, EventHandler`1 action)
at DevExpress.XtraReports.Design.DisplayNameProviderPickManager.GetDataSourceName(Object dataSource, String dataMember, IPropertiesProvider provider, EventHandler`1 callback)
at DevExpress.Data.Browsing.Design.PickManagerBase.<>c__DisplayClass4_0.b__0(IEnumerator enumerator)
at DevExpress.Data.Browsing.Design.ActionExecutor.RunAction()
at DevExpress.Data.Browsing.Design.ActionExecutor.AddAction(Action`1 action)
at DevExpress.Data.Browsing.Design.PickManagerBase.FillContent(IList nodes, Collection`1 dataSources, Boolean addNoneNode)
at DevExpress.XtraReports.Native.TreeListPickManager.FillContent(IList nodes, Collection`1 dataSources, Boolean addNoneNode)
at DevExpress.XtraReports.Native.DataSourceNativeTreeList.UpdateDataSource(IServiceProvider serviceProvider, Object[] dataSources)
at DevExpress.XtraReports.Design.FieldListTreeView.UpdateDataSource(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
at DevExpress.XtraReports.Design.FieldListController.<>c__DisplayClass28_0.b__0()
at DevExpress.XtraReports.Design.FieldListController.ProcessMessage(Action action)
at System.EventHandler.Invoke(Object sender, EventArgs e)
at System.ComponentModel.Design.DesignerHost.OnLoadComplete(EventArgs e)
at System.ComponentModel.Design.DesignerHost.System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.IDesignerLoaderHost.EndLoad(String rootClassName, Boolean successful, ICollection errorCollection)
at System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.BasicDesignerLoader.OnEndLoad(Boolean successful, ICollection errors)
at System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.CodeDomDesignerLoader.OnEndLoad(Boolean successful, ICollection errors)
at DevExpress.XtraReports.Design.NetCore.CRCodeDesignerLoader.OnEndLoad(Boolean successful, ICollection errors)
at System.ComponentModel.Design.DesignerHost.BeginLoad(DesignerLoader loader)
```

Nuget Package Manager:
[image]

I reinstalled Dotnet Runtimes, reinstalled DevExpress tool, reinstalled RepxPackage manually, installed Runtime.Primitives 4.3.0. None have been a solution.

**Edit:
I added new report to same project and same folder and that works, report designer opened. How should i fix old reports to new.**

I copied report c# file and designer to new working report. Thats appeared.
[image]

Thank you for your answers in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wanted to prepare a guideline for those who encounter the same error.

**First** update your databinding sources to object data binding.

If error still exist follow the line:

This error occurs as a result of the report designer (DevExpress tool) not working or the [breaking change](https://supportcenter.devexpress.com/versionhistory#BC3759) after v16.1.

This error goes away when you call the following code block in the constructor with any executing mode in the report.

```
ScriptPermissionManager.GlobalInstance = new ScriptPermissionManager(ExecutionMode.Deny);
```

This applies to reports that are old and have outdated bindings. I replaced them with new expression bindings.

Thanks.